# Is this a correct/efficient way to trim punctuation in python?

Tags: python, string

I have an extremely large set of files that I am iterating over to count all of the words. Words that I am counting can have punctuation in them such as "hyper-speed" or "12:30", but if the punctuation is at the end of the word it should be trimmed. Example ("scary!" => "scary" , "rip-" => "rip"). Here is my algorithm. Everything passed to this function is lowercase.

```
def cleanWord(word):
   if len(word) <= 2:
        return word
    if word[0] in string.punctuation:
        return cleanWord(word[1:])
    if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
        return cleanWord(word[:-2])
    return word
```

Sometimes words are trimmed in my count in awkward ways (such as "philidelphi" or "organiz"), I wonder if this is because in such a large data set there are some mis spellings or if my algorithm is flawed?

Comment: Please doublecheck your indentation in the preview when posting Python code samples especially.

Comment: Almost certainly this is because the text was originally on paper, where if a long word overruns they just stick a hyphen in the middle. This prevents unnecessary line breaks in text but does make processing it rather irritating.

Comment: I would stay away from recursion and do something more "Pythonic" as seen below in jamylak's answer.

Comment: Your code has several problems: you can't give up just because the word has <= 2 letters, consider "--a"; and I think you mean `word[:-1]` (everything up to but not including the last character), not `word[:-2]` (which will skip both the punctuation and the character before it, leading to your "organiz" example.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> word = "-scary!"
>>> word.strip(punctuation)
'scary'
```

As @hughdbrown noted, there are also the `lstrip` and `rstrip` alternatives which only strip from the left and right respectively.

Comment: Maybe you should have punctuation at the start, too, to show that `string.strip` remove leading as well as trailing characters.

Comment: cant believe it's that simple. new to python and I love it.

Comment: Also, perhaps demonstrate mapping this across all the words. `[x.strip() for x in words]`.

Comment: Maybe mention `lstrip` and `rstrip` to contrast with `strip` since the OP is not familiar with `strip`. Also, +1'd this.

Comment: @jhoyla OP is iterating over the words so I'm not sure what operations will be performed on them. Although your comment may help anyway